# Check for updates of a specific Debian package list

Tags: debian, bash, apt, packages, update

#### The setup

I run a Debian Squeeze host that I use to build a multilanguage project (python, java, php...) and generate custom packages (debian and RPM) automatically (through jenkins)

#### The problem

The target distributions of those Debian packages are Etch, Lenny and Squeeze. But our project has some native dependencies that are available only through the `DebianRelease + 1` repository (i.e `Lenny + 1 == Squeeze`, `Squeeze + 1 == Wheezy`). We for example, need the `jetty` packages from Squeeze in Lenny, and the `cyrus-imapd-2.4` packages from Wheezy in Squeeze. Some additional info :

- Some package we can simply 'backport by hand' by mirroring the DebianRelease + 1 packages to our own repositories. For instance, the `jetty` package from Squeeze will run fine on Lenny because it doesn't need an s**tload of additional dependencies
- However we do need to rebuild some packages. For instance, cyrus-imapd-2.4 from Wheezy has a lot of unsatisfied dependencies on Squeeze. So we need to rebuild it in Squeeze and then upload it to our repo.

#### The question

I need to have a simple way of knowing if they are any updates on those extra packages (both "normal" and "security" updates). I could write a simple script that runs weekly, get some parameters from a file, and generate an update report. Let's say the file looks like this:

```
jetty:squeeze
cyrus-imapd-2.4:wheezy
```

The script should run as normal user not to mess up the system apt configuration and issue the appropriate commands to generate that report.

Does Debian has some built-in `apt-*` commands/options dedicated to that kind of problem I could use to write this script ? If not, can someone think of another clean solution to achieve what I need ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I use apt-show-versions for this. Installation is as easy as:

```
# apt-get install apt-show-versions
```

In my /etc/apt/apt.conf I have:

```
APT::Default-Release "unstable";
```

In /e/a/sources.list I have entries for unstable, experimental and at times other temporary repos such as the old emacs-snapshot archive.

Here is an example of a-s-v with an up to date package from experimental:

```
# apt-show-versions -a xmonad
xmonad 0.10.1~darcs20120707-1 install ok installed
xmonad 0.10-4+b2              unstable     192.168.10.1:3142
xmonad 0.10.1~darcs20120707-1 experimental 192.168.10.1:3142
xmonad/experimental uptodate 0.10.1~darcs20120707-1
```

Here is an example of a package that is in unstable and experimental but I only have the unstable version:

```
# apt-show-versions -a zsh
zsh 4.3.17-1 install ok installed
zsh 4.3.17-1 unstable     192.168.10.1:3142
zsh 5.0.0-2  experimental 192.168.10.1:3142
zsh/unstable uptodate 4.3.17-1
```

I can use apt-show-versions to see if there are upgrades in experimental:

```
# apt-show-versions |grep manually| head
autogen/experimental *manually* upgradeable from 1:5.16-2 to 1:5.16.2-2
iproute/experimental *manually* upgradeable from 20121001-1 to 20121001-2
iproute-doc/experimental *manually* upgradeable from 20121001-1 to 20121001-2
```

It is also nice because it will show you packages that are no longer available in any repo:

```
#apt-show-versions |grep -v uptodate |grep "No available"
brscan2 0.2.5-1 installed: No available version in archive
dfc-depends 1.0 installed: No available version in archive
google-chrome-unstable 24.0.1297.0-r162078 installed: No available version in archive
```

Comment: Looks nice, I'll have a look and find out if I that does solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: That's actually a solution that works, except that, for some reasons, the squeeze version of a-s-v output perl errors when I am messing to much with its CLI parameters. Might work better on versions above Squeeze. However a-s-v behaves as advertised, even if after some more search `rmadison` happened to be more suited for my usage.